# Why does image not fill slide container, with 100% width/Height

Tags: javascript, html, css, slideshow

If this is a duplicate apologies I could not find an answer.
I am making a Pure Javascript Slideshow and have nearly done it. However I am facing an issue i cannot seem to resolve.

I cannot get the images to fill the div with 100% width and 100% height. Which once done should slide all images separately, ultimately finishing my slideshow.

Steps taken to resolve:
I have played with the CSS, and changed the position styles between relative and absolute. I have added `width:100%;` to the divs. I have added in an extra style for the images - `#slide li img {width:100%; height:100%};` Yet nothing seems to work. If `#slide li img` & `#slide li` & `#slide` all have width/height at 100% then the first image scales to 100% of the combined images width and height set in the Javascript, Which blows it way out of proportion and will only slide that one image.

I have tried setting the width/height separately in the javascript using document.getElementsByClassName, Yet it still does not fill the contaning div

Here is the code:

```js
function Slide() {
  ul = document.getElementById("slide");
  liItems = ul.children;
  liNumber = liItems.length;
  imageNumber = 0;
  sliderWidth = 0;
  currImg = 0;
  // Left + Right Arrows
  leftArrow = document.getElementById("left");
  rightArrow = document.getElementById("right");

  for (i = 0; i < liNumber; i++) {
    imageWidth = liItems[i].children[0].clientWidth;
    sliderWidth += imageWidth;
    imageNumber++;
  }
  // Set UL's Width as total width of all images in slider.
  ul.style.width = parseInt(sliderWidth) + "px";
  slider(ul);

  function slider(ul) {
    animate({
      delay: 1000 / 60,
      duration: 3000,
      delta: function(p) {
        return Math.max(0, -1 + 2 * p)
      },
      step: function(delta) {
        ul.style.left = '-' + parseInt(currImg * imageWidth + delta * imageWidth) + "px";
      },
      callback: function() {
        currImg++;
        //Keep sliding if not last image
        if (currImg < liNumber - 1) {
          slider(ul);
        }
        // Slide back to first image, if last image
        else {
          leftPosition = (liNumber - 1) * imageWidth;
          //after set seconds, call goback for first image
          setTimeout(function() {
            goBack(leftPosition)
          }, 2000);
          setTimeout(function() {
            slider(ul)
          }, 3000);
        }
      }
    });

    function goBack(leftPosition) {
      currImg = 0;
      setInterval(function() {
        if (leftPosition >= 0) {
          ul.style.left = '-' + parseInt(leftPosition) + "px";
          leftPosition -= imageWidth;
        }
      }, 1000 / 60);
    }

    function animate(opts) {
      start = new Date;
      id = setInterval(function() {
        timePassed = new Date - start;
        progress = timePassed / opts.duration
        if (progress > 1) {
          progress = 1;
        }
        delta = opts.delta(progress);
        opts.step(delta);
        if (progress == 1) {
          clearInterval(id);
          opts.callback();
        }
      }, opts.delay || 1000 / 60);
    }
  }
}
window.onload = Slide;
```

```css
#slidecontainer {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#slide {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}
#slide li {
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  top: 4%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  /* Adjust this value within the range of images i.e 4 images = 25%, 5 images = 20% */
}
.slideimg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="slidecontainer">
  <ul id="slide">
    <li>
      <img src="images/style.jpg" alt="1" class="slideimg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="images/style1.jpg" alt="2" class="slideimg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="images/style2.jpg" alt="3" class="slideimg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="images/style3.jpg" alt="4" class="slideimg" />
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Please do not give a jquery solution, It needs to be Vanilla.

Comment: You could try a 100% css slideshow. See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40075241/css-html-based-slider-show-part-of-next-slide-on-hover

Comment: Yer, I have done a few CSS slideshows before, Issue being i spent the last 2 years avoiding Javascript, doing everything i possibly could in CSS, but i have now hit a point where I NEED to know Javascript...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 1. 100% height

If you want to scale things to 100% of the height of the window, you'll need to make sure enough (when using `position: static`) or *all* (when using `position: relative`) parent elements also use 100% of the height.

In a stack snippet, this means adding these rules to both `html` and `body`, and to all of your own elements.

### 2. 100% width

The width is a bit easier, because every `display: block` element will automatically fill up its parent. To be certain, you can just add a `width: 100%` rule to all of the previously mentioned elements.

The problem your css had, was that each `float` had a width of `25%` relative to its parent, which only had a width of `100%`. Changing this to `400%` (the number of slides * 100), fixes the width.

Here's an example of just the full screen slides. Note:

- I'd swap the tag and id selectors with class selectors if I were you
- I'd use `display: flex` on the `ul` and `flex-grow: 1` on the `li`s instead of float, but both will work.

```css
html,
body,
#slidecontainer,
#slide,
li,
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative; 
}

/* turn this rule on and scroll via js to slide */
#slidecontainer {
  /* overflow-x: hidden; */ 
} 

#slide {
  width: 400%; /* (100 * slideCount) */
}

li {
  float: left;
  width: 25%; /* (100 / slideCount) */
  
  list-style: none;
}

img { 
  display: block;
  background: #efefef; 
}
```

```html
<div id="slidecontainer">
  <ul id="slide">
    <li>
      <img src="images/style.jpg" alt="1" class="slideimg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="images/style1.jpg" alt="2" class="slideimg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="images/style2.jpg" alt="3" class="slideimg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="images/style3.jpg" alt="4" class="slideimg" />
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

---

### Bonus: without javascript

Now, just for fun, here's an implementation without javascript :) It's quite some work to change the number of slides though, so I'd go with a hybrid approach or use a css pre-processor to generate the animation keyframes if I were you. (Only tested in chrome)

```css
html, body, #slidecontainer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
} 

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#slide {
  position: relative;
  width: 400%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  
  animation-duration: 7s;
  animation-name: slide;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

#slide > li {
  flex-grow: 1;
  list-style: none;
}

.slideimg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

@keyframes slide {
  0% {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0); 
  }
  20% {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0); 
  }
  25% {
    transform: translate3d(-25%, 0, 0); 
  }
  45% {
    transform: translate3d(-25%, 0, 0); 
  }
  50% {
    transform: translate3d(-50%, 0, 0); 
  }
  70% {
    transform: translate3d(-50%, 0, 0); 
  }
  75% {
    transform: translate3d(-75%, 0, 0); 
  }
  95% {
    transform: translate3d(-75%, 0, 0); 
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="slidecontainer">
  <ul id="slide">
    <li style="background: green;">
      <img src="images/style.jpg" alt="1" class="slideimg" />
    </li>
    <li style="background: blue;">
      <img src="images/style1.jpg" alt="2" class="slideimg" />
    </li>
    <li style="background: yellow;">
      <img src="images/style2.jpg" alt="3" class="slideimg" />
    </li>
    <li style="background: red;">
      <img src="images/style3.jpg" alt="4" class="slideimg" />
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```